# how to pass a dynamic variable to the OS path to be checked

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to write a few checks which check for the ownership,permissions of a few directories.
Here i need to create the directories if they are not present.However the path needs to be dynamic.
For example in /local/backup/DBNAME the DBNAME would be a variable defined by user input.
So if the user provides the DBNAME as ORACLE_DB1 we would check for:

```
if (os.path.isdir("/local/backup/ORACLE_DB1/log")):
    print('log directory exists')
```

Also 'local' needs be another dynamic variable dependent on server type.
For example if server is type-1 then it is '/local/backup/DBNAME' and if it is type-2 then '/share/backup/DBNAME'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose the path with `os.path.join()` like so:

```
server_path = 'local' if....
db_name = <get the database name from wherever you get it>
filepath = os.path.join(server_path, 'backup', db_name, 'log')
```

You can then check for the path existence and create it if needed.

Comment: can i use a similar approach with os.system to run any command?
like if the directory does not exist  then os.system("mkdir -p /$1/backup/$2/log") where $1 is local or share and $2 is DBNAME

Comment: You seem to be looking for format strings. There are various ways to achieve this in Python: `f"mkdir -p /{local}/backup/{dbname}/log"` (mind the f before the first quotes) that will refer to python variable local and dbname and will only work in Python 3.6+, `"mkdir -p /{}/backup/{}/log".format(local, dbname)` or `"mkdir -p /%s/backup/%s/log" % (local, dbname)` or even the ugly `"mkdir -p /" + log + "/backup/" + dbname + "/log"` Be careful with those because it is trivial to abuse them if you can specify a dbname like `; echo xxxx>>/etc/passwd; #`